# Différence entre "sembler" et "sembler être"

Tags: verbes, infinitif

Y a-t-il des différences entre *sembler* et *sembler être* quand on les utilise avec un adjectif ?

> Ce film semble intéressant.
>
> Ce film semble être intéressant.

Devrait-on utiliser l'un plutôt que l'autre dans certaines situations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je ne sens pas de différence. J'ai essayé avec plusieurs autres phrases, et chaque fois, je ne sentais pas vraiment de différence. Vous pourriez aussi dire:

> Ce film me semble intéressant.

ou:

> Ce film est intéressant.

qui est un peu plus direct - de toute facon, votre interlocuteur assumera sans doute que c'est votre opinion, mais le style est un peu plus léger. Bien évidemment subjectif.